# How to add field to email header in pommo

Tags: php, email, header, field, phpmailer

I want to use custom fields in pommo for List-unsubscribe head, each e-mail contact has own identificator (as field) in contact list which I want to use in pommo to create header f.e. List-unsubscribe: http://domain.com/unsub/?id=**ID_FROM_POMMO_FIELDS**

File: class.phpmailer.php

I think its function CreateHeader()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what pommo is, but I can tell you that if you want to set a custom header in PHPMailer, you just need to do this:

```
$mail->addCustomHeader('List-unsubscribe', "http://domain.com/unsub/?id=$idFromPommo");
```

How you get the ID from pommo is a separate problem.

While on the subject of list-unsubscribe headers, I suggest you read this: http://www.list-unsubscribe.com